# Py2app problems

Tags: python, tkinter, py2app

I have created a python script that uses a tkinter GUI, I have tried to package it using py2app, My problem is that i dont know how to include the tkinter module. I have tried packaging my script without the module but all i get is a console message saying "ImportError: no module named tkinter"

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using python 3.3 for mac

Comment: Does the tkinter example in the py2app repository work?

Comment: No, It gives the same error

Comment: How did you install Python and tkinter? (Python.org installer, self build, home-brew, …)?

Comment: I used the "Python-3.3.0-MacOSX10.6" installer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following setup.py script should do the trick for a basic Tkinter based script (replace 'hello.py' by the name of the actual script).

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    app=['hello.py'],
    setup_requires=["py2app"],
)
```

This is the setup.py script from py2app's [hello_tk example](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/src/default/examples/Tkinter/hello_tk?at=default)

UPDATE:

You mention later on that tkinter cannot be imported from "outside" the py2app'd application either, and that the _tkinter extension (_tkinter.so) doesn't exist. That means that something is wrong with your installation of Python 3.3.

Comment: I would have thought that would work, but as it turns out it doesn't, it just returns the same error

Comment: I don't know why it fails for you, I haven't been able to reproduce the problem :-(.

Comment: And to exclude the obvious: does tkinter work from the command-line (that is, when you run your script without using py2app to create an application bundle)?

Comment: No, it returns this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aspect.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
ImportError: No module named tkinter

Comment: That needs to be fixed first. Things to look into: (1) does 'import _tkinter' work? (2) Does /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so exist (assuming you use the binary installer on www.python.org)? (3) Do the files mentioned in the output of "otool -vL /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so" exist?

Comment: Okay, so 'import _tkinter' returns the error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/student/Aspect.py", line 49, in <module>
    root = Tk()
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined"

Comment: "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/lib-dynload/_tki‌​nter.so" does exist

and im not sure what you mean by the last one

Answer (score 4):

To bundle the app I'm assuming you put this in the terminal:

```
$ python setup.py py2app
```

I also had the same problem and have been ransacking the internet searching for a solution. I am also running python 3.3 on a mac. After I put this:

```
$ python3 setup.py py2app
```

it worked like a charm! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

one way to package the app is running this command:

```
    py2applet --make-setup filename.py
```

Then, you can run:

```
    python3 setup.py py2app -A
```